# Wine / PlayOnLinux dependency issues when trying to install

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies, playonlinux

I am curious as to why installing PlayOnLinux entails removing seemingly unrelated packages like google-earth-stable. Is this the expected behaviour?

This is the output I get when trying to install `playonlinux` through `apt-get`:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python-scour pax ncurses-term
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  binfmt-support fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core libcapi20-3
  libgif4:i386 libmpg123-0 libodbc1 libpam-winbind ttf-umefont
  ttf-unfonts-core unixodbc winbind wine wine-gecko1.4 wine-gecko1.4:i386
  wine1.4 wine1.4-amd64 wine1.4-common wine1.4-i386:i386 winetricks
Suggested packages:
  libmyodbc odbc-postgresql tdsodbc unixodbc-bin dosbox
Recommended packages:
  gettext:i386 unixodbc:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  alien cdbs debhelper dh-make dh-translations gettext google-earth-stable
  intltool intltool-debian lsb-core po-debconf
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binfmt-support fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core libcapi20-3
  libgif4:i386 libmpg123-0 libodbc1 libpam-winbind playonlinux ttf-umefont
  ttf-unfonts-core unixodbc winbind wine wine-gecko1.4 wine-gecko1.4:i386
  wine1.4 wine1.4-amd64 wine1.4-common wine1.4-i386:i386 winetricks
0 upgraded, 21 newly installed, 11 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 145 MB of archives.
After this operation, 275 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

This is the first time I am trying to install Wine / POL. I am using the default repositories, no Wine PPA or POL source added.

These are all the PPAs I am using:

[image]

How do I install POL / Wine without having to remove all these packages?

Comment: I'm giving close vote to this as too-localized since OP already solved the problem

Comment: Looks like conflict between google-earth package and Wine. OP has linked to the bug report.. Closing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went ahead and installed `playonlinux` despite all dependency issues. Turns out that it was no problem reinstalling all the packages afterwards. I still don't quite understand why this was necessary in the first place.

The reinstallation command I used, for you convenience:

```
sudo apt-get install alien cdbs debhelper dh-make dh-translations gettext google-earth-stable intltool intltool-debian lsb-core po-debconf
```

Edit: This seems to be a pretty common occurence ([ex 1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1973282), [ex 2](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/deinstallation-von-google-earth-waehrend-wine-/)) on Precise. [Here's a bugreport on launchpad.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.4/+bug/1007773)

Answer (score 0):

First update package list using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You can Fix dependency by typing command

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Remove unnecessary packages using

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```